# Jenkins cannot find adb with adb folder showing under env variables (Environment Injector Plugin)

Tags: android, macos, jenkins, environment-variables, adb

I need to execute an adb command on my master Jenkins node on Mac OS. I have taken following steps, but still when I try to run adb command the output is `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=2, No such file or directory`

1) I have added adb path to Environment variables on Jenkins>Manage Jenkins>Configure system
2) Once the previous did not work, I have configured my job to `source /Users/displayride/.bashrc`
I also installed Environment Injector Plugin and checking environmental variables for finished builds. 
The adb location is listed there, but I am still getting same error message.

Let me know if more information is needed

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with maven on jenkins. The appium server running on the machine is not able to detect ANDROID_HOME.

This is on appium client 1.7.0
Step 1: Stop appium server
Step 2: Reopen > Edit Configuration
Step 3: There should be an option to set ANDRIOD_HOME and JAVE_HOME

Set the required values.